# Raise an array to different powers

Tags: r, statistics

In R, this code: `c(1,2,3)^2` yields `1, 4, 9` and `2^c(1,2,3)` yields `2, 4, 8`.

Is there a syntactically nice way to combine these two? That is `operation(c(1,2,3), c(0, 1, 2)`, which would give `[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 9]`?

In other words, I'd like to *raise the first array to all values from the second array*.

Is it even possible without resolving to for loops?

Comment: Maybe `outer(X = 1:3,Y = 1:3,FUN = "^")`? (Side note: in R, `c(1,2,3)` is called a vector, or atomic vector, not an array. In R, an array is a multidimensional object, like a matrix.)

Comment: Yes! Post this as an answer to get it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the function `outer`:

```
outer(X = 1:3,Y = 1:3,FUN = "^")
```